# jQuery get Class Name? Only one class to take

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to get a specific class value from element div?**

Simple HTML

```
<h4>THE CLASS NAME FROM THIS DIV IS: 'class1 class2'</h4>
<p id="result-class"></p>
```

Simple jQuery

```
var classFormDiv = $('.class1').attr('class');

$('#result-class').html('result=> ' + classFormDiv);
```

See, https://jsfiddle.net/FIERMANDT/tbqLcx32/

**My answer 21 Jul 2020**

```js
var elDiv = document.getElementById('get-class');

function getClassVal(element, classNameOrIndex) {
  var listClass = element.classList;
  var classValue = '';
  
  switch(typeof classNameOrIndex) {
    case 'string':
      for(var i = 0; i < listClass.length; i++) {
        if (listClass[i] === classNameOrIndex) {
          classValue = listClass[i];
        }
      }
      break;
      
    case 'number':
      classValue = listClass[classNameOrIndex];
      break;
      
    default:
      classValue = listClass.value;
      break;
  }
  
  return classValue;
}

console.log( getClassVal(elDiv, 'class-foo') );
```

```html
<div id="get-class" class="class-foo classic">This element have two class 'class-foo' and 'classic'</div>
```

Comment: @Durga.....This has worked....
See the code below

Comment: [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var classFormDiv = $('.class1').attr('class').split(' ')[0];`
Try this

Comment: thx @Durga it's work.... very awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

use with `split()` like this `classFormDiv.split(" ")[0]` this `[0]` will take the firstclassName .Take the classname as your wish from *array(see the console.log)*

```js
var classFormDiv = $('.class1').attr('class');

$('#result-class').html('result=> ' + classFormDiv.split(" ")[0]);

console.log(classFormDiv.split(" "))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>How to get Class from This DIV? Just one class I want to take</h4>
<div class="class1 class2"></div>

<h4>THE CLASS NAME FROM THIS DIV IS: 'class1 class2'</h4>
<p id="result-class"></p>
```

Comment: THX, VERY AWESOME :D....Very unthinkable to me